# How to check if a belongsToMany association exist in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models in sequelize whose associations have been defined as below

```
Product.belongsToMany(models.Disease, {through: 'DiseaseProduct'});
```

DiseaseProduct table is automatically created by sequelize here and has two columns `DiseaseId` and `ProductId`.

I have gone through the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js~BelongsToMany.html#instance-method-has) several times, but I cannot seem to correctly run the `hasDisease` function to check if a certain disease is associated with a Product (it is always returning false). I can, however, do the below, which runs correctly.

```
var prod = await Product.findByPk(1);
prod.addDisease(1);
```

What I want to do is check the association of the Disease to a product like this below

```
var prod = await Product.findByPk(1);
prod.addDisease(1); //this runs correctly
prod.hasDisease(1); //the promise should resolve to true
```

what I have tried

```
prod.hasDiseases(1);
prod.hasDiseases([1]);
```

Comment: `prod.hasDisease(1)` It returns a promise, try `console.log(await prod.hasDisease(1))`

Comment: Yes, I was using await with the function, it still wasn't running. I have found out the issue. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was with passing the string to `prod.hasDisease()` function.

As I was passing the argument to this function via a request variable in express like below

```
prod.hasDisease(req.body.diseaseId);
```

It was always returning false, although at the same time `prod.addDisease(req.body.diseaseId)` was running without issue and associating Disease via the pivot table.

Anyway, the solution is to convert the string to number like

```
prod.hasDisease(Number(req.body.diseaseId));
```

Can't believe I wasted 4 hours on this!

Comment: Have a proper validation for your request body data before passing the argument to this function. It may also result in `NaN` , which will give you unexpected result.